# Difference between openrowset,Linked server,Opendatasource

Tags: sql

Difference between openrowset,Linked server,Opendatasource and openquery in sql server

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what you're trying to do or how your confused but briefly:
Linked servers allows you to connect to another instance of SQL Server running on a different machine. 
OPENROWSET is an alternative method to accessing tables in a linked server and is an ad hoc method of accessing remote data using OLE DB.
OPENDATASOURCE allows you to connect with using a linked server name.

Take a look on MSDN or SQLServer Central, there are some good summaries and examples on there.